# UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning in Xcode 6 GM

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6, transition

I have a class, `SlideAnimationController`, that is a subclass of NSObject *should* conform to the UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning protocol.

In Xcode 6 GM, I get the error message that my class does not conform to the protocol.

I have implemented `transitionDuration` and `animateTransition`. These are the only two required methods of the three that the protocol calls for.

Adding the last method, `animationEnded`, does not make any difference.

What am I missing? This same code was functional not too long ago.

**Edit**

Here is the class implementation:

```
import UIKit

class SlideAnimationController: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {

    var fromIndex: Int = 0
    var toIndex: Int = 0

    func transitionDuration(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning!) -> NSTimeInterval {
        return 1
    }

    func animateTransition(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning!) {
        //Stuff
    }

}
```

Comment: It sounds like a bug, but can you post some code so we can sanity check it? Perhaps where you declare conformance to the protocol and the method signatures in your implementation.

Comment: @Acey Sure let me add that to the question.

Comment: @Acey I see what is wrong. The !'s are left over from an earlier beta. In this case, because I am not overriding, it does not point the issue out to me. I thought if there were an issue like that, it would do a fix-me like overrides have.

Comment: Yeah that's what I suspected. I was in the middle of installing Xcode 6 GM to test that hah. Go ahead and post your answer and self-accept, I figure you won't be the only person to get stuck on that. They are changing a lot of the APIs to not include optionals when not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug has to do with changes to Swift's versions of Objective-C API's. In many cases where Swift had implicitly unwrapped optionals as arguments, the arguments have been changed to either normal or optional variables.

Normally, when overriding a method, Xcode offers a fix-me to correct these uses of ! where they are no longer needed.

However, since these methods I declared are not necessarily part of the protocol, Xcode recognizes these methods, just does not realize that those are the ones I want for the protocol.

In order to fix this, I needed to remove the !'s from both method parameters (e.g. `UIViewControllerContextTransitioning!` becomes `UIViewControllerContextTransitioning`)